# nasty strip with svg and div

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to build a neon effect for a project, I have create an logo as a svg! I want to dynamically alter the color of the neon sign with css! So I use this mix-blend-color feature! For that I need a background e.g. a div with a background color! Some times this works perfectly find but with certen screen sizes and especially on mobile a nasty strips appear on the sides! Is there any way to fix this? (I only observed this error in svgs)

Here is my code:

```css
div {
    background-color: blue;   
}

img {
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexanderHD27/svg/master/bowldiceD.svg">
</div>
```

Thanks for answering!

Comment: To specify what "nasty strips" means. This blue line at the bottom of the image is this nasty strip, sometimes they occur on the left and right side!

Comment: I use that for a flickering neon sign! Sorry for being no clear! Here is where I put this to use! [my Code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexanderHD27/svg/master/fliker.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were probably overthinking this, the nasty strip is the `background-color` of your parent div, not getting fully covored by the logo.

[image]

On this image the strip is visible, but:

[image]

As soon as I disable the `background-color`, it gets removed.

Nice logo btw.

**Edit**: to remove the strip while keeping the `background-color`, adjust the `display` of the image. I removed both the `width` and `height` properties, because I felt they were now unnecessary and set the `margin` of the body to `0`, you can change that however. [Here](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/wvGqQNK)'s a Codepen.

Comment: Thanks you for answering @Simplicius! disabling the background-color is sadly no option for me! You see the background-color is used to color the logo too! I later I add to my script an animation which alters the background color so it looks like an sign neon which flikers! I used the background color for replacing the black in the logo! Here my code: [myCode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexanderHD27/svg/master/fliker.html)